# how to model bitarrays in django?

Tags: django, model, bitarray

What would be the best way to store a large bitarray within a django model (mysql backend)?

for example, how could i store this object:

```
import bitarray
bits = bitarray.bitarray('11000101010') #real data is 35k bits long
```

Should i just shove it in a CharField?

Comment: anyone? I'm guessing charfield is that way to go....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a BLOB field type that's worth considering.

Or you could converting it to a hex string, prefixed with the length, which would take up less than 9KB:

```
"11,C54"
```

Or ASCII-85, which would take up less space than hex.